# STP Loop issue on long distance link

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, loop

I have long distance connectivity between west coast to east cost datacenter via our ISP network as you can see that in following diagram (BSN=Boston, PHX=Phoenix)

[image]

Now when ISP-A or ISP-B doing any maintenance during that time PHX-SW1 switch putting interface in LOOP* (ofc because BPDU is missing during ISP is down but curious why its thinking its loop and trying to protect link? is there anything i should be doing for long distance STP tuning?)

PHX-SW1-config:

```
interface Ethernet1/1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 4
```

This is the condition when ISP-A is down

```
Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Eth1/1           Root BKN*4         128.1    P2p *LOOP_Inc
Eth1/2           Root FWD 4         128.2    P2p 
Eth1/3           Altn BLK 4         128.3    P2p 
Eth1/4           Desg FWD 4         128.4    P2p 

PHX-SW1# 2021 Aug 31 21:02:10 PHX-SW1 %$ VDC-1 %$ %STP-2-LOOPGUARD_BLOCK: Loop guard blocking port Ethernet1/1 on VLAN0004.
```

when ISP-A is up it unblock interface and everything back to normal.

**Update - 1**

`BSN-SW1` and `BSN-SW2` is in `vPC`

BSN-SW1

```
BSN-SW1# show spanning-tree vlan 4

VLAN0004
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    4100
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    4100   (priority 4096 sys-id-ext 4)
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Po999            Root FWD 4         128.5094 (vPC peer-link) Network P2p 
Eth1/1           Desg FWD 4         128.1    P2p 
Eth1/2           Desg FWD 4         128.2    P2p
```

BSN-SW2

```
BSN-SW2# show spanning-tree vlan 4

VLAN0004
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    4100
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             This bridge is the root
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    4100   (priority 4096 sys-id-ext 4)
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Po999            Desg FWD 4         128.5094 (vPC peer-link) Network P2p 
Eth1/1           Desg FWD 4         128.1    P2p 
Eth1/2           Desg FWD 4         128.2    P2p
```

PHX-SW1

```
PHX-SW1# show spanning-tree vlan 4

VLAN0004
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    4100
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             Cost        4
             Port        1 (Ethernet1/1)
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32772  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 4)
             Address     5254.0018.7292
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Eth1/1           Root FWD 4         128.1    P2p 
Eth1/2           Altn BLK 4         128.2    P2p 
Eth1/3           Altn BLK 4         128.3    P2p 
Eth1/4           Desg FWD 4         128.4    P2p
```

PHX-SW2

```
PHX-SW2# show spanning-tree vlan 4

VLAN0004
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp
  Root ID    Priority    4100
             Address     0023.04ee.be01
             Cost        4
             Port        1 (Ethernet1/1)
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    32772  (priority 32768 sys-id-ext 4)
             Address     5254.0008.b08b
             Hello Time  2  sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface        Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
---------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Eth1/1           Root FWD 4         128.1    P2p 
Eth1/2           Desg FWD 4         128.2    P2p 
Eth1/3           Desg FWD 4         128.3    P2p
```

Comment: Why are you using STP in a meshing scenario that would work *so much better* using routed links?

Comment: You need to set your root bridge. Don’t depend on luck to set it for you.

Comment: My switches doesn’t support L3 at present may be in future I can buy router but not today.

Comment: @RonTrunk I have my root bridge already set on one of switch, do you think root bridge placement causing here?

Comment: @Satish I think you need to post full sanitized configs for both switches involved, to start with. Maybe it’ll help if we can see the full picture.

Comment: You might have a unidirectional link.  The switch sees the Ubuntu server as its root -- that's a problem.  Type `show spanning-tree vlan 4` on all switches and add that info to your question.

Comment: @RonTrunk I have posted command output which you requested

Comment: Looks like you've posted the same info for BSN1 and BSN2.  Both have the same MAC address.

Comment: They are in vPC that is why showing same MAC address

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

xSTP is not a good choice when the link status (up/down) does not reflect actual L2 connectivity.

Your diagram shows an L2 connection between BSN-1 and PHX-1 across different ISPs. Since that is very unlikely, you seem to have some L2 tunneling going on there (VPN?). That tunneling possibly hides the actual link status when connectivity is lost, at least for some time.

You should consider switching to routed L3 links that don't require xSTP for removing bridge loops. Assuming you're using VPN between locations, OSPF between the routers should provide more reliable link status and route propagation.

Comment: I know L3 is best choice but at present i have no L3 switch on both end, until i go buy 5 digit license i am not able to convert them in routed link. (I am ok with loose connectivity because this is not impacting revenue so just looking for some interim solution where i can survive and later when we have money just replace gears.

Comment: @Satish: Maybe abuse LACP as poor man's link state protocol across that link? In extenso: configure LACP with fast timers on both ends, with a single member interface facing that chain of ISPs. This might (more quickly) help both ends understand if the link is up or not.   Be careful though with possible situations for VPC with Orphan Ports

Comment: @Satish I was speculating about the routing equipment that you appear to have in place already - the problem should be solved there.